# How to return JSON result in controller

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I would like to return JSON result in my controller.

In my controller, I am getting an array of `GUID` and passing that to the `CheckRecords` method.

Currently, I am not sure how to get the data back from the data service layer to my controller.

Here is my full code

Controller:

```cs
public JsonResult CheckData()
{
    string guid = HttpContext.Request["GUID"];
    string result = Services.CheckRecords( guid);
    return Json(result);
}
```

Service Layer:

```cs
public static IdIdentity CheckRecords(string guid)
{           
    return DataServices.Services.CheckRecords(guid);
}
```

Interface:

```cs
public interface IServices
{
    IdIdentity CheckRecords(string guid);
}
```

Data service layer where it returns a list:

```cs
public class Services : IServices
{
    public const string PARAM_FORM_GUID = "guid";
     
    public List<IdIdentity> CheckRecords(string guid)
    {
        IdIdentity Code = new IdIdentity();

        if (Code == null)
            return null;            
            
        string sql= "SELECT Name FROM OCODE" +            
            "  WHERE SID IN(SELECT SID FROM OITEMS WHERE OITEM_ID IN (" + PARAM_FORM_GUID + "))";
            

        var parameters = new List<DbParameter>
        {
            CreateParameter(PARAM_FORM_GUID, DbType.String, guid, DBNull.Value),
        };

        sql = ReplaceParameterPrefix(sql);

        return ReadAll(sql, parameters, reader =>
        {
            return new IdIdentity(reader.ReadByName(T_EXCLUSIONS.EXCLUDED_ID, string.Empty),
                reader.ReadByName(T_EXCLUSIONS.EXCLUDED_ID_SCH, string.Empty));
        }).ToList();
    }
}
```

`ReplaceParameterPrefix` function:

```cs
public static string ReplaceParameterPrefix(string sqlString)
{
    if (DataServices.TypeOfProvider == DataServices.ProviderType.SqlServer)
    {
        sqlString = sqlString.Replace(':', '@');
    }

    return sqlString;
}
```

Model:

```cs
[Serializable]
public class IdIdentity : GenericType
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Scheme { get; set; }    
    public string Name { get; set; }
        
    public

    public IdIdentity(string id, string scheme, string name = null)
    {
        Id = id;
        Scheme = scheme;
        Name = name;    
    }
}
```

Please suggest to me how to get the list of result and return it as JSON in my controller.

Comment: just change your controller code to: ` var result = Services.CheckRecords( guid); return Json(result);` and it should work.

Comment: In `Services` class, you will get a compilation error that you didn't implement the method: `IdIdentity CheckRecords(string guid);`. Perhaps modify the return type of `CheckRecords` in `IServices` as `List<IdIdentity>`. The changes will impact to `CheckRecords` method in your Service Layer. You have to amend the return type for that as well.

Comment: And also `string result = Services.CheckRecords( guid);` doesn't make sense. This will also get compilation error for `Services.CheckRecords( guid)` returns `IdIdentity` value, but you assign to a variable with `string` type.

Comment: @YongShun, Can you please provide me an answer. As I mentioned, I want get the value from data service layer and return the those values in json format in my controller. There are few errors. Appreciated, if you could please provide me a solution.

Comment: @Nikolay, Please provide me a solution. How do I get result from Data service layer and pass those results to my controller in json format.

Answer (score 1):

**Issue & Concern**

1. Not implement the method from `IService`.

From your `IService`

```cs
IdIdentity CheckRecords(string guid);
```

and

```cs
public class Services : IServices
{
    public const string PARAM_FORM_GUID = "guid";
     
    public List<IdIdentity> CheckRecords(string guid) { ... }
}
```

You didn't implement the method from `IService` in the `Services` class.

2. Compilation error for assigning the `IdIdentity` value to the variable of `string` type.

```cs
string result = Services.CheckRecords( guid);
```

---

**Solution**

1. Modify the `CheckRecords` method signature to return the `List<IdIdentity>` type in the `IServices` interface.

```cs
public interface IServices
{
    List<IdIdentity> CheckRecords(string guid);
}
```

2. The change in *1* requires you to modify `CheckRecords` method signature to return `List<IdIdentity>` type in Service Layer.

> Service Layer

```cs
public static List<IdIdentity> CheckRecords(string guid)
{           
    return DataServices.Services.CheckRecords(guid);
}
```

3. You should use implicit-type variable (`var`) or explicit-type variable (`List<IdIdentity>`) for the `result` variable.

```cs
public JsonResult CheckData()
{
    string guid = HttpContext.Request["GUID"];
    var result = Services.CheckRecords( guid);  // Implicit-typed
    // Or
    // List<IdIdentity> result = Services.CheckRecords( guid); // Explicit-typed
    return Json(result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Could you please check my data service layer if that is correct. I have more than value for  `PARAM_FORM_GUID` . That means I am passing array of data there.

Comment: Sorry but have to say that you should test your code first. And next raise the error if any. Thanks.